# Do I need to export unsigned .apk before going to create a keystore using eclipse export wizard in Android?

Tags: android, code-signing

I am creating the keystore for my android app using the export wizard. I specified the destination folder and name to create the keystore and then i filled the required fileds like password,alias,exp time,etc. Then wizard promts me to browse for the **Enter destination for APK file**. My question is, **I need to export the unsigned apk or  I need to copy the .apk file form the bin directory of the project?*** 

**Edit**

> Simply put, from where should i browse the .apk file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You not need to browse apk. It ask for where you need to save your sign apk.

You need to provide destination path for `sign apk` at that step of sign apk. It is you sign apk which you have to use for publishing on google play store.

Comment: Sure, after completion of task i will.

Comment: Is there any significance for the alias, First and Last Name, Organisation, Organisation Unit.

Comment: I have already entered password,confirm password fileds. Why it is promting me to enter those fileds again. You have any idea ?

Comment: I think i dont have permission to chat. I didn't find any chat input area.

Comment: Ok. now what issue are you facing ?

Answer (score 1):

No you want to sign the apk.If you signed means it will be updated if you done any changes in

future.And if you given default destination of keystore it will be in eclipse location.For eg:

your eclipse location is in C drive. C/eclipse/your keystore and destination of apk you want

to choose the path location.

And remember first publish will not be a problem, in second edition if u done any changes and uploaded. dont forget to  change in manifest.

```
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" it will be initial release.
```

Next release, change the versioncode and name.

```
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.1"
```

Remember version name should be in decimal and version code should be in integer number.

Comment: thanks for reply, Could you pls Edit your answer and explain me the significance of the VersionCode, VersionName.  Currently i am having **android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0"**.